# Javascript Array Sort function not sorting properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question regarding javascript's sort() function

```
var arr = [23,43,54,2,3,12];
arr.sort();
```

it's output is `[12, 2, 23, 3, 43, 54]`
well it should be `[2, 3, 12, 23, 43, 54]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: it's taking the first digit when sorting as your values represent strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're sorting the numbers with the default sorting algorithm, which converts them to a string and sorts lexicographically.

Instead pass a function defining a sort order via its return value.

```js
var arr = [23,43,54,2,3,12]; 

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Returning a positive number moves `a` toward the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a sort function

```
[12, 2, 23, 3, 43, 54].sort(function (a, b) { return  a - b ; } )
```

The javascript specification states that sort should perform lexicografic sorting, [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: You shouldn't return a boolean. The sorter expects a numeric return value. Returning a boolean may give incorrect results in some cases.

Comment: @spanky you are right, changed to address this feedback,

Answer (score 1):

The sorting of number is based on Unicode.
Hence the oder you have is correct.
Refer the link for details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort