# Javascript "Sort()" function for sorting numbers defined in Mozilla Documentation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

For sorting numbers in javascript we trick function sort() given in Javascript and it works perfectly. The trick is given below:

`[12, 2, 23, 3, 43, 54].sort(function (a, b) { return  a - b ; } )` 
[Source #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161805/9282474) and [Source#2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

I didn't understand what exactly this `a - b` does. I have checked [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/js/src/jsarray.c) but its hard to understand. I checked following answer from stackoverflow but my doubt haven't cleared yet.
[Algorithm of JavaScript “sort()” Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423394/9282474)

Can anyone explain me what exactly happens at `a - b`?

Comment: maybe this helps: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: the callback function you provide to the `sort` property takes as arguments a pair of 2 elements from the array and you define the way they are to be compared, in this case you subtract one from the other to decide which one is bigger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Array.sort implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)

Comment: In this kind of programming you dont care about the actual algorithm that the .sort-method uses you only need to provide a rule thats says for every 2 elements in the list which one comes first. And thats what is defined in ```function (a, b) { return  a - b ; }``` .... so it doesnt actually do anything its more a statement than an instruction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort:

> If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then:
>
> 1. If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b` (i.e. `a` comes first).
> 2. If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.
> 3. If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to an index lower than `a` (i.e. `b` comes first).

When having a array of numbers, `(a, b) => a - b` (a simple subtraction) will thus behave as follow:

- If `a` is greater than `b`, then a positive number will be returned (e.g. 5 - 3 = 2): according to the 3rd rule above, *`b` comes first*.
- If `a` equals `b`, then 0 will be returned (e.g. 5 - 5 = 0): according to the 2nd rule above, *leave `a` and `b` unchanged*.
- If `a` is smaller than `b`, then a negative number will be returned (e.g. 3 - 5 = -2): according to the 1st rule above, *`a` comes first*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this

```
const points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]
```

and you want to sort the array in ascending order, use this:

```
points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
```

for descending order:

```
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
```